# How to use SignalR in WCF Self Hosted Service and consumed by HTML/Javascript application

Tags: javascript, wcf, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have created an HTML/Javascript application which is hosted on IIS and it consumes WCF service using $.ajax methods. I wanted to add realtime communication mechanism using SignalR. I am really stuck into design considerations whether to put SignalR libraries and references inside HTML/Javascript application or into a WCF service.

After going through the documentation it is advisable to use WCF Self Hosted Service for SignalR functionality. I have started adding SignalR and OWIN classes into WCF project but after some time I realized that it is difficult to get it referred in HTML/Javascript application.

I want to setup a client libraries for SignalR and Server components at WCF level.

Can please anybody help me?

Comment: So what is the *exact* problem you're having? Is it adding the owin startup into your wcf service? Is it wiring up the client hub in javascript? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am able to setup the scenario and it is working very well. Here are the steps taken to do so... 
1. SignalR Server [Console Application listening specific port 8081]
2. WCF Service [Running on different port 6781]
3. Javascript Web Application [Running on different port 6226]. It is working so well..... I have gone through SignalR documentation and able to setup above scenario.

Comment: I will share my code after making it more robust....